# Ember js 'ember build' error - Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, symlink

Tags: ember.js, npm

I have a existing quiet old ember.js project which I want to edit/mod. When running 'ember build' or 'ember serve' I get the error below. I read the other issues similar to this but none of the suggestion helped me so far. Can anyone please help how to solve this?

Output from ember version --verbose && npm --version:
ember-cli: 2.5.1
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 5.12.0
v8: 4.6.85.32
uv: 1.8.0
zlib: 1.2.8
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
icu: 56.1
modules: 47
openssl: 1.0.2h
os: win32 x64

---

```
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees: Addon#treeFor (ember-data - addon)] fa
iled with:
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, symlink 'C:\myprojectfolder\tmp\broccoli_merge_trees-output_path-z7GLec0z.tmp' -> 
'C:\myprojectfolder\tmp\broccoli_merge_trees-input_base_path-dgyw33ia.tmp\4'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:945:18)
    at symlinkWindows (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:123:18)
    at symlinkOrCopySync (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:63:5)
    at C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:86:11
    at tryCatch (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at BroccoliMergeTrees.Plugin (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
    at new BroccoliMergeTrees (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\broccoli-merge-trees\index.js:42:10)
    at BroccoliMergeTrees (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\broccoli-merge-trees\index.js:36:53)
    at mergeTrees (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:35:14)
    at Class.treeFor (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\addon.js:300:10)
    at C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:463:20
    at Array.map (native)
    at EmberApp.addonTreesFor (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:461:30)
    at EmberApp._addonTree (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:871:36)
    at EmberApp._processedVendorTree (C:\myprojectfolder\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:916:20)
```

**UPDATE:**
Managed to get ride of the issue by reading the other stack post linked in by Martin where people suggested to use npm clear cache, but for me what really solved the issue was to delete the fields/folders from my windows user temp directory.

Comment: Looks like issue with multi-threaded build. Is there an option to parallelize the processes and they will try to use the same resource? Recently JEST had similar issues on Windows 10 where tests that run in parallel will lock each other out.

Comment: Thx for you input Martin, it is actually windows 7 I am running this. My first guess was permission problem as I run it on a company pc where I have only limited privileges, but the person who originally created this was with the same lvl of perm. I don't think of any multi-threading is involved here (but I could be wrong). It is a 'simply' but old ember project with extra packages added, I use npm for package control and all dependecies seems to be ok, but the problem starts when I try to build it...

Comment: That'e exactly what I mean. ```Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, symlink``` is a file locked by another thread. Check here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13461 Usually this is the cause. Try to clear out the temporary files by hand and then build again. Clear your %%USER%% AppData/Local/Temp and this too: C:\myprojectfolder\tmp\

Comment: Thx Martin! Deleting the user's temp directory solved the issue.

Comment: In general I recommend a `git clean -xfd`. CAUTION: this deletes all files that are not checked in! Also run `ember s` with admin rights in windows.